# Is it possible to use to use two wifi connections in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

Is it possible to use to use two wifi connections in  Ubuntu? if yes then how?

Comment: What do you mean? Connect to two wifi networks at the same time?

Comment: @ Zanna yes.so can get more speed for downloading.

Comment: In theory yes, if the wireless adapter driver and firmware allow it. What wireless adapter (chipset) do you have? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Network` (for internal or PCI devices) or `lsusb` (for USB devices)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking to do is called LINK BONDING
Can be done with software or hardware (additional to your PC)

Simplest way would be to get a router with multiple WAN ports - something like the TP-LINK R480T. It has 4 WAN ports so you can actually connect 4 different ISP modems and then use the router to balance and share what goes over which WAN port in order to improve your performance. Your PC (or any number of PC) connect to the router like normal.....and the router does all the work for the bondng and load-balancing. Last I checked that unit sold for around $50 US
On that router setup just remember Un-check both “Application Optimized Routing” and “Balanced Based Bandwidth Routing”. Otherwise you won’t get combined download speed

Other way is using WINDOWS 8 or 10 load-balancing abilities (built-in) but since we are talking Ubuntu here..I wont go there...

Last is to find a software for Ubuntu that does link bonding and load balancing....then all you need to do is equip your wip with multiple LAN adapters (wireless or wired) and you are off and running. 
3rd party software like this can be a bit unreliable so I have always opted for the hardware option personally